# Съезжают блоки в Safari

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

При открытии сайта в Safari блоки съезжают влево и некорректно отображается шрифт, в других браузерах все хорошо работает. Как быть?

P.S. для наглядности выделил блоки разными цветами. 1-я картинка - как должно быть, 2-я - как выглядит в Сафари

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.footer {
 display:flex;
 display: -webkit-box;                      
 display: -moz-box;                          
 display: -ms-flexbox;                      
 display: -webkit-flex;                      
    -webkit-justify-content:space-between;      
    justify-content: space-between; 
 flex-wrap:wrap;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 margin-top:130px;
 width:100%;
 height: 80px;
 background: #D3D5D6;
 z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: Safari версия  5.1?

Comment: да ......................

Comment: там flexbox не работает

Comment: table, inline-block, вот решение, а flexbox не получится

Comment: на маке тоже не работает или только на виндовс?

Comment: не работает только на виндовс

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex - поддержка флекс